# Test with Rails 4 and Oracle crash when generating the database

Tags: ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4, oracle11g

I develop with Ruby 2, Rails 4.0, and Oracle 11,

When starting with Tests, I couldn't purge neither load the Test Database, many errors appeared:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00900: SQL sentence not valid
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended:
```

Additional Warning appears:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: This database tasks were deprecated, 
because this tasks should be served by the 3rd party adapter. 
(called from mon_synchronize at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the next files and now I can execute 
`rake db:test:load` and `rake test` and database is correctly generated, but warning still appears.

I suppose someone should modify the gems in origin, but who? And if these changes are correct, how can I report this?

File:

> usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@402/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/tasks/oracle_database_tasks.rb

Added: **if (ddl.size>2)**

```
  def purge
    establish_connection(:test)
    connection.structure_drop.split(";\n\n").each { |ddl| 
    connection.execute(ddl) if (ddl.size>2) }
  end
```

File:

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@402/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.5.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_structure_dump.rb

1st Change: Remove **/** from STATEMENT_TOKEN

```
  # STATEMENT_TOKEN = "\n\n/\n\n"
  STATEMENT_TOKEN = "\n\n\n\n"
```

2nd Change: Add **;** after "DROP SEQUENCE..." AND "DROP TABLE....."

```
  # Albert
  def structure_drop #:nodoc:
    statements = select_values("SELECT sequence_name FROM user_sequences ORDER BY 1").map do |seq|
      "DROP SEQUENCE \"#{seq}\";" #Added -->;
    end
    select_values("SELECT table_name from all_tables t
                WHERE owner = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'session_user') AND secondary = 'N'
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT mv.mview_name FROM all_mviews mv WHERE mv.owner = t.owner AND mv.mview_name = t.table_name)
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT mvl.log_table FROM all_mview_logs mvl WHERE mvl.log_owner = t.owner AND mvl.log_table = t.table_name)
                ORDER BY 1").each do |table|
      statements << "DROP TABLE \"#{table}\" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;" # Added -->;
    end
    join_with_statement_token(statements)
  end
```

File:

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@402/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.5.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_schema_statements

(I don't know if this was correct, or I broke this)
Remove: **;**

```
execute "DROP SEQUENCE #{quote_table_name(seq_name)}" rescue nil
```

there was a ;--> "seq_name)}**;**" recue nil

and in same folder

> oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb

there was also a ";", in "...sequence_name)} **;** "), that I removed:

```
  execute ("DROP SEQUENCE #{quote_table_name(sequence_name)}")
```